# Command output to console & grep to assert success status

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am running a python script which creates google cloud dataflow job. The command looks like this

```
python -m runpipline <command_options ...>
```

The output of this command gives if the job was created successfully or not. In case of successful creation, the command ends like this

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Create job: <Job
 createTime: '2020-02-18T20:39:44.885028Z'
 currentStateTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'
 id: '2020-02-18_12_39_43-1111111111111111111'
 location: 'us-central1'
 name: '<name_of_the_job>'
 projectId: '<project_name>'
 stageStates: []
 startTime: '2020-02-18T20:39:44.885028Z'
 steps: []
 tempFiles: []
 type: TypeValueValuesEnum(JOB_TYPE_STREAMING, 2)>
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Created job with id: [2020-02-18_12_39_43-1111111111111111111]
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:To access the Dataflow monitoring console, please navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/jobsDetail/locations/us-central1/jobs/2020-02-18_12_39_43-1111111111111111111?project_name%
```

This script is being run by github action and is using `ubunt-latest` image. What I want to do is

1. The output of the command should be print to console AND I should be able to extract the job_id from the command
2. If I am able to extract job id, i should be able to do next X command.
3. If job_id doesn't exist then I should fail the script.

I used `grep` to do this `python -m runpipline <command_options ...> | grep -E "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{19}\]"` but this would stop me from outputing to console. Also, It just gives me the line which matches this criteria. not the job id. So not sure what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
id=$(python -m runpipline <command_options ...> | tee /dev/tty | grep -Po "id:\s*\[\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{19}(?=])")

if [[ -n $id ]]; then
    : # do your command here
else
    echo "grep failed"
fi
```

- It searches the `python` output for the id preceded by a string `id: [` and followed by `]`.
- Thanks to the lookaround assertion, only the id portion is assigned to the variable `id`.
- You can continue your task by using the result.

**[EDIT]**
If your `grep` does not support the `-P` option, please try the following instead:

```
id=$(python -m runpipline <command_options ...> | tee /dev/tty | grep -Eo "id:[[:blank:]]*\[[[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){2}(_[[:digit:]]{2}){3}-[[:digit:]]{19}]")

if [[ -n $id ]]; then
    id=$(sed 's/^id:[[:blank:]]*\[\(.\+\)]/\1/' <<< "$id")      # remove leading and trailing extra substrings
    echo "grep passed. Id=$id"
else
    echo "grep failed"
fi
```

Comment: I used your command and it failed. I have put details here https://gist.github.com/underscore-ex/58e3edf6ad302bb08cff8adb2f0f0430

Comment: It looks like the `grep` command failed perhaps it has some options which aren't available? I am using `ubuntu-latest` image on github actions

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It seems your `grep` does not support the
`-p` switch which enables the Perl-compatible regex.
I have updated my answer appending an alternative without the `-P`
option. Hope it will work. FYI I am testing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which is
much older than yours and the bundled `grep` works with the `-P` option. BR.

Comment: Using `| tee /dev/tty` definitely seems like the right approach if you want to both write to stdout and process that output. You can iterate on the exact grep incantation you need.

Comment: @dimo414 thank you for the comment. Yep, that is the point I have puzzled over. If the matched substring (id) is not used in the following procedure and "true or false" only is required, there will be more approaches.

Comment: it worked :) ... just one concern (since i have no idea about shell script). the output is `grep passed. Id=id: [2020-02-18_12_39_43-1111111111111111111]`. The id is with in the square brackets i.e., `2020-02-18_12_39_43-1111111111111111111`, how can i remove `[` and `]`.

Comment: @EmAe Good to know we are almost there. As for the brackets, I've intended to
remove them with the `sed` command in the statement `id=$(sed ..`.
I'm not sure why it's not working but as a workaround,
please put the code `id=${id#*[}; id=${id%]*}` in place of the `sed` line.
The code above removes any characters before `[` inclusive, and after `]`
as well. Hope it will work. BR.

Comment: @EmAe thanks for the feedback. Good to know it works. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have that api with us which generates your shown output so not tested it fully, could you please try following once.

```
cat script.ksh
OUT_FILE="/complete_path/output_file"
python -m runpipline <command_options ... > "$OUT_FILE"
if [[ -s "$OUT_FILE" ]]
then
     cat "$OUT_FILE"
     JOB_ID=$(grep -ioP ".*Created job with id:\s+\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_(\d{2}_){2}\d{2}-\K(\d+)(?=])"  "$OUT_FILE")
     if [[ -n "$JOB_ID" ]]
     then
          echo "Run your further programs here......"
     else
          echo "Looks like NO job id found, exiting from script now... bye!!"
          exit 1
     fi
else
     echo "Please check your Python program has NOT created output file."
     exit 1
fi
```

---

---

***What does script do?***

- Script is having a BASH variable named `OUT_FILE` whose value is COMPLETE PATH of your file with file name where we want to store output of your Python command.
- Then it runs your mentioned Python api(you could fill complete command there, I just used an example only provided by you in your samples).
- It saves output of it in output_file at given by your complete path.
- Now comes an if condition which checks if output_file is having size in it, means NOT NULL size then it goes further else it comes out of the script saying "Your python command didn't create any output file."
- Now it uses GNU `grep` command to find out the job's id with  `\K` and regex and saves it into variable named `JOB_ID`.
- Next is a condition if variable is NOT NULL then you could run your further commands there where I mentioned like `Run your further programs here......`
- In case there is NO job id found if variable `JOB_ID` value is NOT NULL then script will exit saying `Looks like NO job id found, exiting from script now... bye!!`

Comment: is there an option where i don't have to create an `output_file`?

Comment: @EmAe, I thought of it but then it was becoming a oneliner which was not easy to understand so I went for this approach, also if you don't need a output file we could delete this at last of script, till then I will also think of other way f it, lemme know if this has worked out for you at least, I will be Happy if this has worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that does what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd_output=$(python -m main --project_id <project_name> --topic_name <topic_name> --job_name <job_name>i) #captures the INFO output to a variable
id=$(grep -m 1 -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{19\}' <<<  $cmd_output ) #extracts the job id from the variable

#now we can see if a valid id was generated 
if [[ -n $id ]]; then
  >&2 echo "$cmd_output" #you wanted to output both the INFO and id.  This outputs the INFO to stderr
  echo "$id" #this outputs the ID to stdout and can be captured as the result of your script
  #put next commands here
else
  #you can put an error message here if you want 
  exit 1 #non-zero exit indicates failure
fi
```

Let me know if you need anything else.